# Adding Dictionary to a value of another Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following scenario ::

```
public static class ServiceErrorCode
{
    public static IDictionary<string,Dictionary<int,string>> Mappings
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    static ServiceErrorCode()
    {
        Mappings = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,string>>();
        Mappings.Add("Unauthorized", new Dictionary<int,string>().Add(103,"Test"));//Error is has some invalid arguments

}
```

Can anybody help how can i achieve the above and if i want to retrieve the inner dictionary values(both 101 and Test) using outer dictionary key (Unauthorized), then how can i achieve this ?

Please help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing one  closing parenthesis at end

Comment: Added .But still the same error.

Comment: ``var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            dictionary.Add(103, "Test");
                Mappings.Add("Unauthorized",dictionary)``

Comment: ``Add()`` return type is void so thats the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Add` method returns `void` - so you can't use it as a method argument. However, you can use a collection initializer:

```
Mappings.Add("Unauthorized", new Dictionary<int,string> { { 103, "Test" } });
```

That's roughly equivalent to:

```
var tmp = new Dictionary<int,string>();
tmp.Add(103, "Test");
Mappings.Add("Unauthorized", tmp);
```

... but the collection initializer is easier to read, IMO.

Comment: Thanks . Can you please give a solution in a single line instead of defining tmp then adding the same to Mapping

Comment: @vivek: Um, I have. That's the first part of the answer.

Comment: The 1st part of the answer gives the following error ::
"No overload for method 'Add' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: @vivek: Ah - missed a pair of braces. Fixed.

Comment: Can you please help me to retrieve both inner dictionary values (103, "Test" ) using outer dictionary key (Unauthorized)

Comment: @vivek: Not in this question, no. That sounds like you should ask a new question showing what exactly you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what happened. Note that there aren't two values - there's one *entry*, with a key of 103 and a value of "Test".

Comment: Thanks ..I already mentioned in the question regarding how to get those inner dictionary values.Do i still need to ask a different question for it ?

Comment: @vivek: Well there isn't enough detail in the question at the moment, and ideally a question should be about solving *one* problem - you've shown the problem creating the dictionary, but there's no information about what you've tried or what result you've got when trying to retrieve the values. (Fundamentally, you can get the dictionary as `var dict = Mappings["Unauthorized"];` - it's then just a normal dictionary, so you should explain what you're finding hard about using that - the fact that it's nested in another dictionary to start with is irrelevant.)

Comment: Ok Thanks . I will look into it .

Answer (score 0):

Mappings.Add("Unauthorized", new Dictionary());
Mappings["Unauthorized"].Add(103,"Test");